# How to get user id using C# for Flickr API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flickr

I am using Flickr API for retrieving user image for my school project.

I have used search-box to fetch image using key-words which user enters, for adding extra features I want to display images of user by default, for that I need to get users id but I am not getting.

Comment: please show what have you done pal. please try something. its the only way to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Flickr C# library that may be of interest for you. It's called [FlickrNet](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/) and comes with source code to some [example applications](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

Also, have a look at [this](http://hectorcorrea.com/Blog/Flickr-Library-in-C-Sharp) Flickr API wrapper for C#. It's a light-weight class that helps you perform some basic functionality such as retrieving user sets and info about user photos in a set.